# Using JUnit with App Engine and Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, junit

I am having trouble setting up JUnit with App Engine in Eclipse. I have JUnit set up correctly, that is, I can run tests that don't involve the datastore or other services. However, when I try to use the datastore in my tests they fail. The code I am trying right now is from the App Engine site (see below):

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/localunittesting.html#Running_Tests

So far I have added the external JAR (using Eclipse) appengine-testing.jar. But when I run the tests I get the exception below. So, I am clearly not understanding the instructions to enable the services from the web page mentioned above. Can someone clear up the steps needed to make the App Engine services available in Eclipse?

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/appengine/api/datastore/dev/LocalDatastoreService
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.testing.LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig.tearDown(LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig.java:138)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.testing.LocalServiceTestHelper.tearDown(LocalServiceTestHelper.java:254)
at com.cooperconrad.server.MemberTest.tearDown(MemberTest.java:28)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:37)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:73)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:46)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:180)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:41)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:173)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:220)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:46)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.appengine.api.datastore.dev.LocalDatastoreService
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
... 25 more
```

Here is the actual code (pretty much copied from the site):

```
package com.example;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreService;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceFactory;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query;
import com.google.appengine.tools.development.testing.LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig;
import com.google.appengine.tools.development.testing.LocalServiceTestHelper;

public class MemberTest
{
    private final LocalServiceTestHelper helper = new LocalServiceTestHelper(new LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig());

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        helper.setUp();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        helper.tearDown();
    }

    // run this test twice to prove we're not leaking any state across tests
    private void doTest() {
        DatastoreService ds = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
        assertEquals(0, ds.prepare(new Query("yam")).countEntities());
        ds.put(new Entity("yam"));
        ds.put(new Entity("yam"));
        assertEquals(2, ds.prepare(new Query("yam")).countEntities());
    }

    @Test
    public void testInsert1() {
        doTest();
    }

    @Test
    public void testInsert2() {
        doTest();
    }

    @Test
    public void foo()
    {
        assertEquals(4, 2 + 2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In Eclipse, have you added all the jars mentioned [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/localunittesting.html#Introducing_App_Engine_Utilities)?  You need a few more jars than just appengine-testing.jar.

> However, if your tests or code under test have these dependencies you'll need a few more JARs on your testing classpath: ${SDK_ROOT}/lib/impl/appengine-api.jar, ${SDK_ROOT}/lib/impl/appengine-api-labs.jar, and ${SDK_ROOT}/lib/impl/appengine-api-stubs.jar. These JARs make the runtime APIs and the local implementations of those APIs available to your tests.

Comment: Thanks Peter, that did the trick. The documentation made it sound like an either or situation (at least to me) but once I added the three jars mentioned above everything worked.

Comment: Mark and Peter, what does your .classpath file look like?  Mine has lines like "<classpathentry kind="lib" path="${SDK_ROOT}/lib/impl/appengine-api-labs.jar"/>", but this doesn't work.  Is "${SDK_ROOT}" code, or am I to fill the path in?

Comment: This solved my problem but I had to figure out where to find the 4 jar files referenced in Peter Recore's solution.  In Eclipse (Juno) I went to Project=>Properties=>Java Build Path=>Libraries=>Add External JARs.  Then (on my Mac) I navigated to Applications\eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.9.9\appengine-java-sdk-1.9.9\impl and I selected the 3 JAR files.  Then I went back up a directory and down into the testing directory to get the 4th JAR, namely appengine-testing.jar.

Comment: I can not find appengine-tools-sdk.jar as mention on the link. There are only 3 of them. Where can I download it?

Answer (score 1):

[Peter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3055029/873165) is correct: you need these libraries:

```
appengine-api.jar
appengine-api-labs.jar
appengine-api-stubs.jar
appengine-tools-api.jar
```

Chances are you already have the first one and only need the last three.

If you're using Maven, you can add these dependencies to `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
  <artifactId>appengine-api-labs</artifactId>
  <version>1.9.60</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
  <artifactId>appengine-api-stubs</artifactId>
  <version>1.9.60</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
  <artifactId>appengine-tools-sdk</artifactId>
  <version>1.9.60</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```